# Transferring information securely across domains

Tags: php, security, api, ssl, payment-gateway

HI guys have a bit of a logic question. I have a client that does event registration on sites A. B. and C. and they would like to start taking payments for the registrations. Now it would be a bit outlandish to create a payment platform on each site so I'm thinking of handling all the payments on an external source say, site D. now, what i'd need to do is create some sort of API that will receive payment data and handle it accordingly (I.E. process, reject, return messages etc.). My biggest concern is A. the security of this and B. really differentiating between clients (site A. B. and C.) and the possibility to vastly expand in the future.

Is just transferring this data from an SSL secured site to another good enough? Should I be passing variables along with it? Thanks guys.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard. In short, if you've never worked with handling, processing, storing, communicating credit-card transactions.. don't do it yourself. Pay someone qualified and learn from them. I don't mean to sound crass but a bug in an application that deals with money is 1000% more terrible than a normal bug.

Comment: SSL is not going to help you much, you probably meant TLS

Comment: Mike thanks, I wouldn't be storing sensitive information and I would be using a third party like authorize.net. I guess what I want to do is just handle it on a different domain. I'd also use a library like... https://github.com/calvinfroedge/codeigniter-payments

Comment: @Woot4Moo, "*SSL is not going to help you much, you probably meant TLS*": what do you mean? (Granted, if you're going to use SSL/TLS nowadays, you might as well use TLS 1.0 at least.)

Comment: @bruno i was getting at that op should be using the latest standard not the old.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, fair enough... Most people still refer to SSL or TLS as "SSL", including most APIs and SSL/TLS stacks (Java's `SSLSocket`, .Net's `SslStream`, Python's `ssl` module, ...). SSLv3, TLSv1.0, 1.1, 1.2 is mainly a configuration change when using SSL/TLS (the higher the version number, the better it is, indeed, but it's not the only thing that matters for a good SSL/TLS usage).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of payments your best bet is to find a [PCI compliant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) payment processor who will allow you to [tokenize card data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_%28data_security%29).

The end result of tokenization is that you no longer need to pass sensitive data around but instead pass a token that represents a card. While you'll still want to pass this information in a secure manner it's useless to a 3rd party unless they can get your credentials for the payment provider.

If you choose *not* to do this then you will need to become PCI compliant yourself which means you have to provide to a 3rd party auditor that you are storing this information in a secure manner which is both expensive and time consuming.